# Using lua to program a turtle in Computercraft minecraft to farm using coordinates

Tags: lua, coordinates, minecraft, computercraft

I have a square 7x7 square field. I am trying to have as less movement as possible to reduce fuel consumption.

[image: I find this path the easiest path]

Like a graph, I am trying to assign coordinates to certain points. I could use the blue thing in the middle (water) as the origin, but it seems like using the most bottom left block seed as the origin also works.

This is what I have so far:
[image]

The problem I am having is when it is going to change rows. The easiest way to do is going to back to the x minimum, which consumes a lot of fuel and time. Is there a way for the turtle bot to know which direction to go to change to the next row?

Comment: What do you mean by "I am hoping to see if I could use coordinates to lead my turtle where to go." because at the end you ask "The problem I am having is when it is going to change rows." wouldnt it be the easiest way to do it as anybody else and listen to a redstone signal under the turtle, which activates your script and then pass trough every field and harvest it? By the way there is a "IDE" for turtles called turtlescripts.

Comment: Thank you! I fixed the small error. Just for curiosity's sake, is there a way to do it fully with just programming the turtle and without sensing redstone signals?

Comment: I guess you could use the internal timer of the turtle, and/or a wifi turtle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code traverses a field in the manner you desire. While simple, it works, but could benefit from some abstraction to make it usable for other purposes.

```
local rowSize = 7
local colSize = 7
local turnLeft = true
local skipMove = false

function goHome()
   local r,c
   turtle.turnLeft()
   turtle.turnLeft()
   for c=1,colSize-1 do
      turtle.forward()
   end
   turtle.turnLeft()
   for r=1,rowSize-1 do
      turtle.forward()
   end
   turtle.turnLeft()
   turtle.back()

function harvestRow()
   local c
   for c=1,colSize do
      if skipMove == true then
         skipMove = false
      else
         turtle.forward()
      end

      turtle.digDown()
   end
end

--
-- Move and orient turtle onto next row
--
function nextRow()
   if turnLeft == true then
      turtle.turnLeft()
      turtle.forward()
      turtle.turnLeft()
      turnLeft = false
   else
      turtle.turnRight()
      turtle.forward()
      turtle.turnRight()
      turnLeft = true
   end
   skipMove = true
end

--
-- Call to start farming
--
function harvestField()
   local r
   for r=1,rowSize do
      harvestRow()

      -- go to next row unless its the last
      if r~=colSize then
         nextRow()
      end
   end
   goHome()
end
```

Best wishes on your farming endeavors and thank you for the opportunity to dust off some old Turtle API knowledge.

Comment: Thank you so much! There was a minor error, but other than that, it works really well. The alternation between left and right works beautifully and inspired me with my other turtle projects.

Comment: @m_cht Glad you found it useful. What was the minor error? Did I mess something up copying the copy into the answer?

Comment: At function harvestRow(), you did "skipMove == false" instead of making it a variable. Just a tiny mistake though. Thanks again.

Comment: @m_cht Thx for the feedback. I corrected the code in the answer, just in case others copy it for their own use.

Answer (score 1):

If it will always be 7x7 (or any odd width), you could make a home for the Turtle on the other side. That way, it doesn't waste fuel having to travel back.

For all sizes, you could also turn based on the row's parity (even or odd). If it always starts in the bottom-right corner, it will turn left after the first, right after the second, and so on:

```
rowCnt = 1;
if rowCnt%2 == 0 then --even row number
  turtle.turnRight()
else --odd row number
  turtle.turnLeft()
end
```

Comment: This suggestion is not unreasonable; however, more complex turtle setups may have mechanisms to auto-load fuel and other items. Not having a well-define home would require duplication of blocks supporting a turtle.